# Trigger in MYSQL that updates different column depending on value inserted

Tags: mysql

I have a structure in a database where I have a question table that has 4 columns for the results so , int id,string question, int a, int b, int c, int d

And the answer table which has int id, int user_id, int question_id, string answer.

Now the answer in the answer table can be a, b, c or d and in the question table I have the amount of each answers.

What I want to do is create a trigger that will automatically increase the value on the respective column when a new answer is inserted.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `answer_INSERT` $$
CREATE TRIGGER `answer_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `answer`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF(answer.answer LIKE ('a'))
        UPDATE `question` SET `a`=`a`+1 WHERE `id`=answer.question_id
    ELSE IF(answer.answer LIKE ('b'))
        UPDATE `question` SET `b`=`b`+1 WHERE `id`=answer.question_id
    ....
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I know that the code is not closely correct, but that is more or less what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `answer_INSERT` $$
CREATE TRIGGER `answer_INSERT` 
AFTER INSERT ON `answer`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.answer = 'a' THEN
        UPDATE `question` SET `a` = `a`+1 WHERE `id` = NEW.question_id;        
    ELSEIF NEW.answer = 'b' THEN
        UPDATE `question` SET `b` = `b`+1 WHERE `id` = NEW.question_id;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You need to change the delimiter to something else than `;`. Other the trigger definition would end at the fitst `;` which would make it incomplete. If your trigger would be really simple and does not contain a `;` then you don't need to change the delimiter first to something else.